# How to convert meters into feet with 2 decimal digits in ASPX page

Tags: html, asp.net, converters, dimensions

Can someone help me with displaying feet units correctly converted from meters?
In my ASPX page I got the below code. I don't know how show feet with 2 digits after the decimal point. I would like to show something like this:  **2.067m = 6.78 ft**

I tried to play with several formats of the result string, such as #.#, #.##, #.#0, but nothing works in the way I would like above. Can you please help me out?

My URL is https://cargobid.org/iso-container-guide.aspx.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
     <span class='<%# IIf(Double.Parse(Eval("insideLenght"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) = 0, "hidden", "col-md-6")%>'>
     <%# Container.DataItem("insideLenght")%> m</span>
     <span class='<%# IIf(Double.Parse(Eval("insideLenght"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) = 0, "hidden", "col-md-6")%>'>
     <%# Convert.ToInt32(Container.DataItem("insideLenght") * 3.2808399000000001).ToString("#.##")%> ft</span>
<span class='<%# IIf(Double.Parse(Eval("insideWidth"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) = 0, "hidden", "col-md-6")%>'>
     <%# Container.DataItem("insideWidth")%> m</span>
     <span class='<%# IIf(Double.Parse(Eval("insideWidth"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) = 0, "hidden", "col-md-6")%>'>
     <%# Convert.ToInt32(Container.DataItem("insideWidth") * 3.2808399000000001).ToString("#.#")%> ft </span>
     <span class='<%# IIf(Double.Parse(Eval("insideHeight"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) = 0, "hidden", "col-md-6")%>'>
     <%# Container.DataItem("insideHeight")%> m</span>
```

'>
<%# Convert.ToInt32(Container.DataItem("insideHeight") * 3.2808399000000001).ToString("#.###")%> ft 
         '>
<%# Container.DataItem("doorWidth")%> m
'>
               <%# Convert.ToInt32(Container.DataItem("doorWidth") * 3.2808399000000001).ToString("#.##")%> ft 
'>
              <%# Container.DataItem("doorHeight")%> m
'>
           <%# Convert.ToInt32(Container.DataItem("doorHeight") * 3.2808399000000001).ToString("#.#0")%> ft

Comment: Not sure what do you want, can you show us what did you archive? Your code doesn't form well, too, so it hard to detect what did you do

Comment: Ì don't know what you mean with "archive". I just want to use properly the following tag: ToString("#.#"). It is not working no matter which format I choose for the results. Either #.## or #.#0 or #.# has no effect at all in th results. I need 2 decimal cases after the decimal point on the feet results. This is really strange why it doesn't work!

Comment: what i mean is whatever you did, please show us. And your code is not correct, how can we replicate it

Comment: Hi Jacky. Can you please tell me which part of the code is incorrect? Because the conversion on the webpage is working properly, as you can see..